# Necessary steps to calculate photon's path by using null geodesic equation

Tags: astrophysics, cosmology, fundamental-astronomy, general-relativity, observable-universe

Can anyone please give me an explanation on how to calculate photon's path by using the null geodesic equation? N.B. I know all of the non-zero values of Christoffel symbols.

Answer (score 2):

The geodesic equation below is a second-order partial differential equation for the spacetime coordinates $x^\mu$, $\mu = 0 \ldots n$, $${d^{2}x^{\mu } \over ds^{2}}+\Gamma ^{\mu }{}_{\alpha \beta }{dx^{\alpha } \over ds}{dx^{\beta } \over ds}=0 \;,$$
where $\Gamma ^{\mu }{}_{\alpha \beta }$ are the Christoffel symbols, and the proper time $s$ is the parameter of the curve (i.e. how ``far along'' you are on the path). You need to solve these $n+1$ coupled equations as any such system, e.g. numerically.

If the parameter $s$ is confusing, you can reparametrise the curve as a function of coordinate time $t = x^0$, as explained e.g. on Wikipedia's page on [geodesics in general relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity), $${d^{2}x^{i} \over dt^{2}}=-\Gamma ^{i}{}_{{\alpha \beta }}{dx^{\alpha } \over dt}{dx^{\beta } \over dt} + \Gamma ^{0}{}_{{\alpha \beta }}{dx^{\alpha } \over dt}{dx^{\beta } \over dt}{dx^{i} \over dt} \;,$$
which gives you $n$ partial differential equations for the spatial coordinates $i = 1 \ldots n$. (Note that there are remaining greek indices, for which $dx^0/dt = dt/dt = 1$.)